# Using Google Maps to highlight whole roads

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been looking everywhere for a way to highlight a whole roads on a Google Map via the API.

As in, I want some roads to be highlighted red, others green etc.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find anywhere that mentions it. I'd like it to look like how it does when you view the traffic data on a map via maps.google.com.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please accept it so that the question won't continue to show up as unanswered.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I also need to be able to highlight a road - given a road name only.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to highlight roads of a certain type, you can use Styled Maps:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html

If you want to highlight a specific road, you would have to create a polyline overlay:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines
To do that you would need to have the coordinates for the road, which Google does not provide